# Preparing model, view and projection matrices for glsl

Tags: java, matrix, glsl

I'm using the [vecmath](https://java.net/projects/vecmath) library to help with matrix maths while I'm converting opengl program to utilize `glsl` better.

After writing question I guess I've 3 small questions:

- Where does the model matrix get it's value from?
- Do I need to reset all model, view and projection matrices inside `display()`? i.e every frame
- Do I reset mode, view and projection matrices after drawing each object?

This is how I calculate my `projection` and `view` matrices within the `reshape` function of my `GLEventListener` ..

```
Matrix4f mProjectionMatrix = createPerspectiveProjection(
    60.0f, width / height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
Matrix4f mViewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
mViewMatrix.setIdentity();
```

Helper function ..

```
private Matrix4f createPerspectiveProjection(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar){

    Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();

    float yScale = (float) (1 / (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2))));
    float xScale = yScale / aspect;
    float frustrumLength = zFar - zNear;

    mat.m00 = xScale;
    mat.m11 = yScale;
    mat.m22 = -((zFar + zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m23 = -1;
    mat.m32  = -((2 * zFar * zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m33 = 0;

    return mat;
}
```

Inside `display()` of `GLEventListener`, I'm unsure about next steps.

Conceptually I have following in my head, are these the right steps I need to perform? ..

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable){

    // reset view matrix, needed?

    // Calculate the model view projection matrix .. where does model matrix get it's values from?

    // translate to Square1's position?
    // rotate to Square1's angle?
    // draw Square1 .. passing MVP matrix

    // translate to Square2's position?
    // rotate to Square2's angle?
    // draw Square2 .. passing MVP matrix
}
```

This is my vertex shader ..

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Comment: [SO]'s recommended format is one question per thread. While your subquestions may be more or less closely related, it is nonetheless a good idea to consider their possible separation into separate question threads. It will improve your chances of getting good answers to each of them and also will be in accordance with [SO]'s recommendations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I keep three matrices in my OpenGL applications. They are the **Model**, **View** and the **Projection** matrices. All these matrices are sent to the shader using the uniforms and the shader does this.

```
gl_Position = mProj * mView * mModel * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

That is, the position is by default in the local object space. Multiplying it with the **Model** matrix applies the translation, rotation and scaling for that model, and the transformed vertex is now in the world space.

Now the vertex is multiplied by the **View** matrix, which applies the transformations of the camera, like the camera position and the orientation. Now the vertex will be in the eye space.

Finally the vertex is multiplied with the **Projection** matrix, applying the effect of either perspective or orthographic, which depends on what I chose to use. Finally after the transformation, the vertex will be in normalized device coordinates (ranging from **-1** to **+1**) and will be rendered by the OpenGL.

> Where does the model matrix get it's value from?

The model matrix is by default, an identity matrix. Whenever you want to only transform the entity and not the entire world, you will multiply the transformation matrix with the model matrix and set the result as the new model matrix. This allows you to keep separate attributes for each instance of a model in the scene.

> Do I need to reset all model, view and projection matrices inside `display()`? i.e every frame?

No you don't. You can create the matrices once, but whenever the value of the matrices change on the client side, that is, your program, you have to update the uniforms in your shader program.

> Do I reset mode, view and projection matrices after drawing each object?

No you don't. Usually you will keep one projection and one view matrix, but several model matrices per each object you have in your scene. The projection usually won't change in the entire course of the application, so there is no need to re-update it. The view matrix, is with your camera, so usually it will also be one for the entire scene. The model matrix, however will be different for each object, so you have to update it every frame.

> Where do you get your Model matrix values from? i.e what are they generated from?

There are certain formulae which creates those matrices, like the helper method you have above which generates a perspective projection matrix based on the field-of-view and the aspect-ratio of the camera lens. It is hard to explain all those formulae here, so you can see the source code of my `Transforms` class which has such functions.

See the source code for my [Transforms](https://github.com/sriharshachilakapati/SilenceEngine/blob/master/silenceengine/src/main/java/com/shc/silenceengine/math/Transforms.java) class on my GitHub repository. It's not completely documented, but I think you can use them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for input @Sri, where do you get your `Model` matrix values from? i.e what are they generated from?

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Updated the answer. Check it now.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati: (quoting from your answer:) "the vertex will be in clip coordinates (ranging from -1 to +1)". Clip space is _not_ in range [-1,1]. In _normalized device coordinates_, the viewing volume is represented as the [-1,1] cube. Clip space is _before_ the perspecitive divide, and the viewing volume is [-w,w] there - however, the `w` may vary for each vertex, so this is actually hard to imagine as a 3D cube.